# Infection from website

Tags: malware, websites

I wanted to learn more about keyloggers and how to protect myself from them. I clicked on a result from google, but the site seems to be infected.

[Link to Sucuri results](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/znservices.co.uk/6560af-Vst_Plugins_For_Adobe_Audition_fileinfo/188215/Keylogger_Download.html)

Do I need to reinstall my computer?

Comment: Then if you just clicked at the link and closed it - you don't have to worry. If you installed any program, macros, etc. from it or entered your credentials there - you probably have a problem.

Comment: We cannot perform a site analysis to determine what your specific risk is. Now, you searched for keyloggers and the link is to a keylogger download. It is expected that a scan would show a ... keylogger.

Comment: I haven't downloaded anything, I was just redirected to another website. Is it possible for the website to have downloaded something in the background, executed it and made changes to the BIOS? Is reinstalling the OS sufficient?